# Coupon code being applied to other products when the eligible product is in the cart

Tags: coupon, coupon-codes

i couldn't find any info on this hence posting it here. Basically I have 30% discount on one single category. We had a case today where the client was able to use that 30% on the whole cart. I did some digging around and the reason was a single product from that category was in the cart.

e.g. 5 items

- item 1: (eligible) £45
- item 2: £35
- item 3: £55
- item 4: £45
- item 5: £35

The total came to £155.49 but it should of been £201.50

**My coupon rule is as follow:**

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
Category  is  21
```

*Category 21 is the category which is eligible for the discount.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a **Shopping Cart Price Rules**. If you want products of a specific category to be 35% off, create a **Catalog Price Rule** instead.

Just go to menu `Promotions > Catalog Price Rule` and click in **Add New Rule.**

Fill all the information, put the condition as you did above and in the tab **actions** insert the 35% off.

Don't forget to click in **Save and Apply**, otherwise you will not see the changes in your website.

Comment: Sorry but I'm trying to create a coupon code that can be used by the client.

Comment: Oh my bad. Did you try insert conditions in the Actions tab (Apply only to cart items matching...)?

Comment: By adding the same rule again under further processing the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue simply go to the action part of your coupon and apply the same rule again to the "apply the rule only .." Check picture for more info.[image]